# variable not registering in for loop

Tags: r, loops

This seems to be a basic problem. I am attempting to loop through a list of variables to determine the shapiro-wilk statistic. However, the `var` is not registering anything in the loop. It appears as "NULL (empty)" in the environment window of RStudio.

The test works fine outside of the for loop. Any thoughts on what needs to be corrected here?

```
library(broom)    
data = "some data.csv"    
vars = list("var1", "var2")
     for (var in names(vars)) {    
          sw <- tidy(shapiro.test(data$var))
          write.csv(sw, file = "shapirowilk_pvalue_" + var + ".csv")
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT1** Following the advice in the comments, the revised (and now working) code is:

```
vars = c("var1", "var2")
for (var in vars) {
  sw <- tidy(shapiro.test(Data[[var]]))
```

The syntax for the `write.csv` is not working...

**EDIT2**
The full working code is below, which writes to a text file:

```
sw_pvalues <- data.frame()
vars = c("var1", "var2")
for (var in vars) {

  sw <- tidy(shapiro.test(Data[[var]]))

  tempvalues <- cbind(var,sw)
  colnames(tempvalues) <- c('variable', 'sw_stat', 'pvalue', 'method')
  sw_pvalues = rbind(sw_pvalues, tempvalues)

}
write.csv(sw_pvalues, file = "shapirowilk_pvalues.csv")
```

Comment: `data$var` is shorthand for the data's `"var"` column (which doesn't exist).  You want to use `data[[var]]`.

Comment: Try using the data[[var]] instead of data$var.  One needs to programmatically access the variable.

Comment: Also, (I'm not sure if your code is just pseudo code, but) `names(list('var1', 'var2'))` evaluates to `NULL`, so that might be impacting your for loop.

Comment: I switched to `[[var]]` but no change in the output. It seems that `var1` should be set in the `for` line, regardless of how the shapiro test is specified.

Comment: The elements of the list (`var1` and `var2`) are field headings of the `data` table.

Comment: @MrFlick, I looked at the two questions you considered to be duplicated with and it appears that my situation is unique given that replacing `$var` with `[[var]]`did not help. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Use `vars = c("var1", "var2")` (just use a vector rather than a list), and use `for (var in vars)` for the loop. Still use `shaprio.text(data[[var]])` in the loop.

Comment: @MrFlick, changing to `vars = c("var1", "var2")` still does not help. This is very perplexing to me.

Comment: And you change the for loop to not use `names()`? Edit your question to show what you are currently actually trying.

Comment: Ah, yes. All set now. Many thanks MrFlick. Still need to work on concatenating my filename, but should be ok with that

Comment: The original question has been edited to include the final working code, including writing results to a single text file with variable names